# Genesys development

Tags: gwt, genesys

Has anyone used GWT (Google Web Toolkit) to develop applications working with Genesys servers? I'm trying to do that and I'm confronted with the famous error:

```
"No source code is available for type com.genesyslab.platform.commons.protocol.ProtocolException. Did you forget to inherit a required module?"
```

and other errors of the same type but with different classes. Of course, I've already searched for solutions and all I've understood is that this error is recurrent in GWT and it's inherent to the framework. GWT tries to translate my java code to javascript, and the GWT compiler needs to get access to the source code to make those translations.

So my question is: Has anyone had this problem before? If so, have you been able to solve it and how so?

Answer (score 2):

You can't as you need the source code as mentioned, which Genesys won't release to you.